# How to add my custom header to a HttpServletRequest with aspect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I tried to create an aspect to override the
`HttpServletRequest`
parameter before the controller handler method actually gets executed. But it turns out the `HttpServletRequest` is always a `RequestFacade` instance even though I replace it with a Custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper` in my aspect method.

Here is the code:

```
// the annotation:

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}

// the aspect:
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.springtest.annotation.MyAnnotation)")
    public void pointcut() {
    }

    @Around("pointcut()")
    public Object setHeader(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        var args = pjp.getArgs();
        var signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        var method = signature.getMethod();
        var annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        var need = Arrays.stream(annotations).anyMatch(a -> a.annotationType().equals(MyAnnotation.class));
        if (!need) {
            return pjp.proceed();
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            var arg = args[i];
            if (arg instanceof HttpServletRequest request) {
                args[i] = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                    @Override
                    public String getHeader(String name) {
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("my-header")) {
                            return "my-header";
                        } else {
                            return super.getHeader(name);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

}

// the bootstrap class:
@Configurable
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringtestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringtestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

// and the controller
@RestController
public class TestController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @MyAnnotation
    @GetMapping("/get-my-header")
    public String getMyHeader(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(request) instanceof HttpServletRequestWrapper) {
            log.info("is wrapper");
        } else {
            log.info("request:{}", request.getClass());
        }
        return request.getHeader("my-header");
    }
}
```

So what happend there? Is there any other proxy class instance change my `HttpServletRequest` parameter after I replaced it?

the logs show that the request parameter in both the aspect and the controller is a `RequestFacade` instance.

I also tried to create a service method and directly send my custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper` instance to it. This time the parameter is not changed.

Comment: Don't use AOP for this, instead use a servlet filter to wrap all the requests instead of this. There might be more things in the call stack that wrap your request (things like Spring Security for instance) so you would have to check if the request is a wrapper and keep unwrapping it to check if yours is in there. If you really want to use AOP for this (which I strongly recommend against) instead of calling `proceed()` you need to call `proceed(args)` to pass along the newly changed arguments, else it will continue with the original ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid fiddling with request headers' modification is not that easy. I am also afraid that aspect is not a way to go.

Here is a minimal and reproducible sample for Spring Boot 2 to achieve what you want by setting a named `attribute` to the request in a custom interceptor that is captured in a method of the `@RestController`.

**Interceptor**

```java
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        request.setAttribute("fooAttribute", "fooValue");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private CustomInterceptor customInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(customInterceptor);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

I let the attribute be returned in the body.

```java
@GetMapping("hello")
public ResponseEntity<String> hello(@RequestAttribute String fooAttribute) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(fooAttribute);
}
```

---

Test it out:

```bash
curl http://localhost:8080/hello
```

> ```
> fooValue
> ```

Comment: Hi! The interceptor approach using url pattern to match controller is somewhat more error-prone compared to the aop approach with custom annotation. Is there any better way to choose which controller I want to intercept? Thanks for you answer.

Comment: i mean, i have to write a url-pattern based on the current url for every api and i have to change it if someone changes the intercepted url later. By adding an annotation this will not bother me. I'm also wondering why the aop approach is not working.

Comment: @patrickstar: Interceptor is a standard way of intercepting REST communication. If you find it error-prone only because of the URL-pattern, feel free to remove `addPathPatterns("/**")` and it will work for all endpoints. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I want it to work for some endpoints I choose. I will try the interceptor way. Thank your ^_^ @Nikolas Charalambidis